# How To Use The inAppWebView Of The Url_Launcher As A Widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to show  a web page inside my program , so I'm using url_launcher package unfortunately the launchUrl method opens the web page in a new screen and I don't want that , I want to use it as a widget so I can put it in the body of a scaffold for having appbar and bottom navigation bar in my screen

any ideas how I can do that ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve your problem using this package: [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). The default behaviour of url_launcher is that it launches the url in a new `web_view`. Also, you can't embed that webview in flutter widget tree.

So, you should use the inappwebview package.
For ex:
In your widget's build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       body: InAppWebView(
       //Configure your properties according to your need. See docs.
       ),
   );
}
```

For more information see its docs: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/5.x.x/webview/in-app-webview/